# Connection between adjoint of a matrix and adjoint of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, adjoint-operators

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with
$$T(x,y) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1x+2y \\
3x+4y \end{array} \right] $$

The matrix representation of $T$ is 
$$ A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
 \end{array} \right].$$

Now the adjoint of the operator $T$ is the transpose of $A$
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 3 \\
2 & 4
 \end{array} \right],$$

> "Adjoints of operators generalize (conjugate) transposes of square
>   matrices."

On the other hand, the adjoint of the matrix $A$ is 
$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
4 & -2 \\
-3 & 1
 \end{array} \right].$$

Is there any connection between the two? or the two "adjoint" definitions used here are unrelated.

Thanks!

Comment: The second "adjoint" here is sometimes referred to as the [adjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between adjoint in linear algebra and adjoint of operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496363/the-difference-between-adjoint-in-linear-algebra-and-adjoint-of-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are mistaken.  The adjoint of the matrix A is the transpose of the matrix A.

One major confusion here is that there are two definitions for the word adjoint.  The adjoint of a matrix is its conjugate transpose.  Another definition, now often called the "classical adjoint" of a matrix is the matrix of its cofactors, which is what I think you write as the adjoint of the matrix A.  Another now more common name for the classical adjoint of a matrix is its adjugate.

Comment: I see, they are two different things. Thanks for the clarification.